# PHP - Regex : I need help to build regex according these rules

Tags: php, regex

I need help building a regular expression for `preg_match` according these rules:

1. first and last char- letter/digit only.
2. empty space not allowed
3. char can be  only - letter/digit/'-'/'_'/'.'

**Legal examples**:

1. b.t612_rt
2. rut-be
3. rut7565

**Not legal example**:

1. .btr78; btr78-    (first/last allowed chars)
2. start end; star  t     end;                (any empty space)
3. tr$be; tr*rt; tr/tr ...  (not allowed chars)

Edit: I remove 4 rule with neigbor chars '_'\'-'\'.'

please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try writing one yourself, and we can help you if it doesn't work as intended? You'll never learn anything if you ask others to do all your work for you without even attempting it first.

Comment: [Open-source alternatives to RegexBuddy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) lists a few nice tools to help with constructing a regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+([-_.][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

This matches any sequence that starts with at least one letter or digit (`^[A-Za-z0-9]+`) that may be followed by zero or more sequences of one of `-`, `_`, or `.` (`[-_.]`) that must be followed by at least one letter or digit (`[A-Za-z0-9]+`).

Comment: +1 for simplest solution without a bunch of look-ahead stuff.

Comment: @dani: Then replace `[-_.]` by `[-_.]+`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}][\p{L}\p{N}_.-]*[\p{L}\p{N}]$
```

In PHP:

```
if (preg_match(
    '%^               # start of string
    [\p{L}\p{N}]      # letter or digit
    [\p{L}\p{N}_.-]*  # any number of letters/digits/-_.
    [\p{L}\p{N}]      # letter or digit
    $                 # end of the string.
    %xu', 
    $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Minimum string length: Two characters.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for each of your rules:

1. First and last letter/digit:

   ```
   ^[a-z0-9]
   ```

   and

   ```
   [a-z0-9]$
   ```
2. empty space not allowed (nothing is needed, since we're doing a positive match and don't allow any whitespace anywhere):
3. Only letters/digits/-/_/.

   ```
   [a-z0-9_.-]*
   ```
4. No neighboring symbols:

   ```
   (?!.*[_.-][_.-])
   ```

So, all together:

```
/^[a-z0-9](?!.*[_.-][_.-])[a-z0-9_.-]*[a-z0-9]$/i
```

But with all regexes, there are multiple solutions, so try it out...

**Edit: for your edit**:

```
/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_.-]*[a-z0-9]$/i
```

You just remove the section for the rule you want to change/remote.  it's that easy...

Comment: @meagar: fixed, I didn't add the any character match to the forward assertion.  It should work now

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine for provided examples: `$patt = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-._][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/';`